# Proxy Request in PHP

Tags: php, proxy, request

I have an application hosted on US server and I am using it to connect to another service in US. So the request is made from a US IP. I want to make the request from an IP of visitors country.

Is this possible ? Can we do this with PHP ?

Comment: No. You cannot forge IPs for TCP connections, except the initial SYN packet. It is not possible to do a full 3-way handshake with spoofed/forged IPs unless you have control over the target site's routers. This is not a PHP limitation. It's a fundamental limitation of how the internet works.

Comment: So how those proxy sites work?  Even though Some websites are blocked in my country, I can access them using a proxy site

Comment: The proxy site isn't faking an IP. If you're in (say) canada and using a proxy site in (say) Mexico, to hit a server in the U.S., then the u.s. site will see a hit come in from a mexican IP. As a canadian I can't really use Hulu, but if I rent a US-based proxy, I can hit it easily because the traffic to Hulu appears to be coming/going to US IPs.

Comment: So if i am using from canada and I have a proxy at mexico the request goes to US server as mexican IP right ?

Comment: Yes. There'll probably be an `X-Forward-For: canada ip here` header in there somewhere, but a PHP script running on the US server would hav e$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` be your proxy's mexican IP, not your canadian one.